# Metro UI on an Android App

Tags: android-layout, microsoft-metro, android

I am currently developing an app where my user interface would be similar to that of the METRO UI of windows app but not very similar. I made a relative layout where the "windows" would be places. Given that I have formatted them properly. How do I add simple animations such as changing images on each window on display (ie. without having to let the users touch in order to trigger animations.)

[Here](http://metro-webdesign.info/) is an animation I would like to imitate but would start even without user touch/hover.

Comment: Not an answer, but do you really want to do that? Users generally prefer consistent design across apps, so your app imitating metro UI will most likely be confusing to most users. It's better to create a _native_ feeling of your app on each platform than to be the same on every platform.

Comment: I don't know much about Android UI Design. Is there a definitive guideline on how to create a UI that complies with the common UI on Android?

Comment: There's a dedicated site: http://developer.android.com/design/index.html  Also I recommend watching "Android Design in Action" on youtube

Comment: Well, I guess the Flipboard UI design is still similar to the Metro UI. Would you agree? https://lh3.ggpht.com/ckbX2V3HA0KOd61zePzWHvtYjQT-ZM3rueyHYaneTIw_emziabnQhh9Ohcg2Ab6bpWw

Comment: Yes, Flipboard has rectangles, but in my opinion it doesn't really feel like metro (spacing between tiles, and the rectangles aren't squares). Don't get me wrong: You're still allowed to not use the Android design guidelines. But you shouldn't _contradict_ the guidelines. E.g. the flipboard screenshot shows way to small icons to refresh and settings at the bottom. Either they should be bigger or go into the overflow menu at the top right. The search box feels weird too. So don't take them as a good example. They're doing stuff wrong. Oddly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an Asynctask and call it recursively, (ignore the types of the parameters):

```
public class AnimateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... vURL) {
//do some waiting
//trigger animations
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String a) {
    AnimateAsyncTask atsk = new AnimateAsyncTask();
    atsk.execute();
    super.onPostExecute(a);

}
```

Comment: Would not try it now because I would like to study more about the Android UI design. But don't worry, I would try it some other time in order to have an answer to my question. Thanks!